# Log username/password for 401 authentication error spring boot

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-boot, spring-security

I want to log username and password for a given authenticated web service.

I have my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` configured as following:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/webservice/path").fullyAuthenticated().and().
        httpBasic().and().
        csrf().disable();
    }
```

what I want is to get http request and log the user name and password like in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31807634/855758)

so what I want is how do I get the http request for my web service in spring boot and log the credentials regardless if user and pass are correct or not.

Answer (score 3):

Consider adding a LoggingFilter in your application.

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean loggingFilterRegistration() {

    FilterRegistrationBean loggingBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    loggingBean.setFilter(loggingFilter());
    loggingBean.addUrlPatterns("/login");
    loggingBean.setName("loggingFilter");
    return registration;
} 

@Bean
public Filter loggingFilter() {
    return new GenericFilterBean {
       @Override
       public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
              if("POST".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())){
              // Implement Logging logic here
              }
      }
   }
}
```